# asp core azure 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure

Опубликовал на azure проект ASP Core. Выдает ошибку 404(страница не найдена), на любые адреса (прописывал контроллеры, методы).  Но если положить стандартный html в wwwroot, то он открывается(и только он ).

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

На вопрос может быть миллион ответов  в зависимости от случая.
Я не создал бд в azure, и она кидала ошибку.

Узнать о проблеме можно если активировать **"Log stream"** в настройках **App service**

И еще, может пригодится: я не мог создать базу данных из visual studio при создании **App service**, потому что выдавало не информативную ошибку. она заключалась в том что при создании сервера я указал пароль который содержал часть логина(звучит как бред, но если создавать сервер и бд через azure, то именно такая ошибка и будет, а в студии почему то нет...).